# JavaScript & PayPal Checkout Button Question

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, checkout, paypal-rest-sdk

I am currently testing out the sandbox for the PayPal checkout integration using Javascript.

I see how to use the "Sandbox" mode versus using the "Live" mode when testing our buttons out in Javascript.

What I'm asking is how do I set the product's title so that the buyer can see exactly what they're about to purchase prior to clicking the "Pay Now" button to finalize the transaction?

Here is the code that I'm currently working with as shown below:

```
//HTML GOES HERE TO CONTAIN THE PAYPAL BUTTON
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?&client-id=[MY-CLIENT-ID-GOES-HERE]&merchant-id=[MY-MERCHANT-EMAIL-ADDRESS-GOES-HERE]&currency=USD"></script>


paypal.Buttons({
    style: {
        layout:  'vertical',
        color:   'gold',
        shape:   'pill',
        label:   'buynow'
    },

    // Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({

        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: 50, // Can reference variables or functions. Example: `value: document.getElementById('...').value`
            currency: 'USD'
          },

        }]
        
      });
      
    },
    
    // Finalize the transaction after payer approval
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
        // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
            var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
            alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');

        // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:
        // var element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
        // element.innerHTML = '';
        // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
        
        actions.redirect('https://SomeWebsiteURLiWillForwardThemTo.com');
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In paypals docs you can see the purchase unit object. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-purchase_unit inside that object you can see that you can pass an items array. This is an array of objects that you can view here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-item. You can define the parameters of each product including the name. So in your case I think you can try something like the following:

```
purchase_units: [{
  amount: {
    value: 50,
    currency: 'USD',
    breakdown: {
      item_total: {
        currency_code: 'USD',
        value: 50
      },
    }
  },
  items: [
   {
     name: 'Product Name',
     unit_amount: {
       currency_code: 'USD',
       value: 50
      },
      quantity: '1'
    }
  ]
}]
```

Here is a working fiddle just pop in your client id to test. [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/8xftd4Ls/)

NOTE: Look at the docs and see what are required fields. I also think that you need to apply a breakdown to the amount for this to work.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this before, but when I try to test the "items:" option in sandbox (haven't tried "live" yet), the new PayPal window tries to open up and load, but then it quickly just crashes and closes right back down immediately.


Here's what I just tried a couple of minutes ago, then it keeps crashing:

Comment: // Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({

        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: paypal_price, // Can reference variables or functions. Example: `value: document.getElementById('...').value`
            currency: 'USD'
          },
          items: [
            { 
              name: 'Product Name'
            },
          ]
          
        }]

    
      });
      
    },

Comment: Yes, I've tried this before, but when I try to test the "items:" option in sandbox (haven't tried "live" yet), the new PayPal window tries to open up and load, but then it quickly just crashes and closes right back down immediately.
@Steve K

Here's what I just tried a couple of minutes ago, then it keeps crashing:

Comment: `// Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({

        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: paypal_price, // Can reference variables or functions. Example: value: document.getElementById('...').value
            currency: "USD"
          },
          items: [
            { 
              name: "Product Name"
            },
          ]
          
        }]

    
      });
      
    },
         `

Comment: You need to add a breakdown to the amount I think for this to work. Like I said in the note before you need to look and see what fields are required. Unfortunately Paypals docs are a mess and its like following the breadcrumbs and is really easy to miss something. I updated the answer with working code and a fiddle demo. You can see the product and total breakdown if you click the down arrow by the price in the checkout now.

Comment: Thanks again Steve! Seems to be working now. I think it would be even nicer if PayPal gave the option to already have that drop down already set to dropped down in case the buyer doesn't see it to click it and see exactly what the product or service title is that they're about to purchase. Anyhow, thanks again.

Comment: Hi , can any one say me how to add tax value in its ...

Comment: @user3209031 https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-item in the item object you can see the definition for the tax value.

Comment: Thanks, steve do u have  php server side full demo , can u please share ? means after transaction is completed , i need to send that data in my database